# How can I reduce this circuit to a source in series with a single impedance?

Tags: thevenin

How can I Thevenize the following circuit looking into the out terminal:

[image]

I want to deduce this circuit to a source and a single series impedance.

Here what I tried:

\$\frac{R1\cdot R2}{R1+R2}\$ is in series with C1

This becomes \$\sqrt{\frac{R1\cdot R2}{R1+R2}^2 + \frac{1}{\omega C1}^2 }\$

And now \$\sqrt{\frac{R1\cdot R2}{R1+R2}^2 + \frac{1}{\omega C1}^2 }\$ is in parallel with R5

I cannot proceed more. How could this be achieved if mine is wrong as an alternative way?

is the following correct?:
\$\frac{R1\cdot R2}{R1+R2}\$ is in series with C1

\$Z_{thevenin} = \frac
{\sqrt{\frac{R1\cdot R2}{R1+R2}^2 + \frac{1}{\omega C1}^2 } \cdot R5}
{\sqrt{\frac{R1\cdot R2}{R1+R2}^2 + \frac{1}{\omega C1}^2 } + R5}\$

And the Thevenin voltage needed to be found as well.

Vth = V1 * ((|R5+(1/jwc)| // R2)/ (R1 + (|R5+(1/jwc)| // R2))) * R5/|R5+(1/jwc)|

Comment: Why can't you proceed more? Do you know how to use phasors? Do you know the frequency of operation?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Is the stage where I am at correct? Frequency is ω so it is variable.

Comment: You have lost the phase information. Does that matter to you? I would use impedances and phasors. Do you know how to use phasors?

Comment: Yes I know how to use phasors, phase does not matter just the amplitude

Comment: And Im not trying to find Vout in temrs of Vin. I want to reduce the whole thing to a Thevenin resistance-. A source and a single impedance. Thats why I didnt use phasors.

Comment: Looks to me like you're overcomplicating things. What if C1 was a resistor, could you then solve this? If yes, replace C1 with an impedance \$Z_{C1}\$. Then treat \$Z_{C1}\$ as if it is a resistor. Apply Thevenin. Then fill in \$Z_{C1} = 1/j\omega C_1\$ and you have your answer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I think when I see Zc1 in series with R, to find the equivalent impedance  I was doing sqrt(Zc1^2+R^2) instead of Zc1+R. I migth be mixing up phasors and this way of solution.

Comment: Would you not simply use Voc/Isc to get impedance?

Comment: @scorpdaddy finding Voc is almost the same struggle. Maybe you may write an answer. No one bothered to answer yet,

Comment: @user1999 you are probably interested in "Mesh Loop Analysis" as a way to find Voc, Isc.  You can google for "mesh loop analysis examples".  Videos and tutorials come up.  Such as, "https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/mesh-current-method/".

Comment: @scorpdaddy Not really I just wanted to reduce the circuit to one source and one output series impedance. I think I made it see my edits

Comment: @user1999, are you asking how to solve the problem yourself? Or are you asking someone to solve it for you?

Comment: @scorpdaddy I needed help but meanwhile I solved it but not 100% sure . Now it is in my question maybe someone can verify whether it is correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do not make any mistake in the math the correct equation for \$Z_{th}\$ will look like this:

$$Z_{th} = \frac {\sqrt{R5^2 + (\omega\ C_1\ R_T\ R_5)^2}}{\sqrt{1+(\omega\ C_1 (R_T+R_5))^2}}$$

Where:

$$R_T = \frac{R_1 \cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

And the Thevenin voltage

$$Vth = V_{IN}\cdot\frac{R_2||R_5}{R_1 + R_2||R_5}\cdot \frac{\omega\ (R_T +R_5)C_1}{\sqrt{1 +(\omega\ (R_T + R_5)C_1)^2} }$$

Comment: Can you also add Vth? Then it would be complete and to reduced one source and a single impedance.

Comment: I believe it should  be handled down a canonical ratio of polynomials to have a better understanding of what this impedance does over frequency

Comment: I add Vth voltage.